# How to force the pointers not to keep their values and orderings from launch to launch?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, heap-memory

Preamble: assume I have the following C++ program:

```
int main()
{
    int *p1 = new int;
    int *p2 = new int;
}
```

It turns out that from launch to launch p1 and p2 will have the same values and p1 < p2.

Now the problem: I have a large program with multiple memory allocations on the heap. It turns out that with a rather high stability the pointers to the allocated memory bulks will have the same values from launch to launch and, consequently, their ordering will also be kept. But I want pointers not to keep their values and orderings from launch to launch. How can this behaviour be achieved with minimal changes to the existing code?

Maybe, the problem can be solved by not changing the code, but by writing some accessory program. I thought about launching another process which would perform frequent memory allocations/deallocations, but the different processes don't share the address space, so it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: *Why* do you want the pointers not to keep their values? This seems like a very strange request.

Comment: What? Both will have a default value of 0 as it should. Anyways making indeterministic program for a purpose makes no sense to me, it's a hell to debug any bug.

Comment: @Melkon OP is talking about the pointer addresses, not the values

Comment: @Melkon, If you mean `*p1` and `*p2`, both of those values after these lines are indeterminate, not necessarily zero.

Comment: Who cares what the pointer values are between runs?  It is just a handle to some memory.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by this? Your question doesn't make much sense as it is - the values of pointers is usually unimportant as long as they point to valid memory.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Depending on the system this may be a security issue.

Comment: @Simon Kraemer: He wrote "p1 and p2 will have the same values", not address.

Comment: @chris : You are right, sry.

Comment: He just wants the addresses to be allocated randomly. You could create a factory to provide your objects although it would add a performance cost.

Comment: @Melkon Depends on the point of view. For me the `p1` and `p2` are pointers which have addresses as values. You were most probably talking about `*p1` and `*p2` what I referred to as values. Nevertheless: None of these will be zero if the memory isn't already zeroed by random.

Answer (score 2):

At program startup, allocate a bunch of pointers to random length blocks, then `delete` some random portion of them in a random order.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you would like to do some sort of stress testing of your program. Your approach with a process performing frequent memory allocations and deallocations puts you on the right path, except that the allocations need to be done in the same address space as your running process, i.e. it should be a separate thread, not a separate process.

Write a thread that starts at startup and quits on request. The thread should randomly allocate and de-allocate chunks of memory of random size, and keep the chunks that it allocates in a list. The thread should wake up every now and then, pick N random chunks from its list, and deallocate them. Then it should allocate N random chunks, put them on the list, and go back to sleep.

When thread shutdown is requested, the thread should free all its memory chunks, and exit.

Your `main()` should start the thread on startup, and run the "payload" portion of your program. Once its done, `main` should signal to the thread that it should exit, and `join` to the thread in order to let it complete its deallocations. Even though you no longer going to need the memory the thread holds, it should be allowed to run to completion, in order to not interfere with memory profiling tools, such as [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).